# Appending Words to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to append the incorrect words to a list, however when I print the list outside of the function it is empty and when I print it inside the function it prints a list for each word. How do I get the list to print just one time with the incorrect words in it at the end of the program?

File 1:
this is my spell checker program

File 2: dis is my spll cheker program

So there are 3 incorrect words that should be added to the list

```
word_list = []

if cmdlength != 2:
    print ("Usage error, expected 2 args got " + str(cmdlength))
    exit()
else:
    try:
        f = open(sys.argv[1])
        f.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
        exit()
    try:
        ff = open(sys.argv[2])
        ff.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File does not exist")
        exit()
    word = ""
    with open(sys.argv[1],"r") as fh:
        while True:
            ch=fh.read(1)
            if ch == " " or ch == "\n" or ch == ":" or ch == ".":
                with open(sys.argv[2],"r") as fh2:
                    def check_word(word,fh2,word_list):
                        lines = fh2.readlines()
                        for line in lines:
                            x= re.search(word,line)
                            if x:
                                #correctwords
                                print(word + ": " + "0")
                                #count += 1
                            else:
                                #incorrect words
                                print(word, ": " , "1")
                                word_list.append(word)
                                #count2 += 1
                    check_word(word,fh2,word_list)
                word = ''
            else:
                word += ch
            if not ch:
                print(word)
                print("End of file")
                print(word_list)
                break
```

Comment: What function are you referring to when you say "outside the function"?  I don't see any user-defined function in the code you posted, it just looks like top-level code.  Is your code inside a function block that you're not showing us?

Comment: This is not a working script - it would help if your script was a minimal working one that we could then run and analyse...

Comment: You should also provide us a sample file so that we know what we're working with and can attempt to recreate the problem

Comment: @JohnL. The function is defined inside the `with` block

Comment: Updated the post with the files. It runs, just not the correct way. Function is inside the with block because the file being opened is passed as a parameter to that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is missing a `return` statement to return `word_list`.
This should work

```
...
def check_word(word,fh2,word_list):
    lines = fh2.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        ...
        word_list.append(word)
        #count2 += 1
    return word_list

word_list = check_word(word,fh2,word_list)
```